# opencv_annotation (-204:Requested object was not found)

Tags: opencv

`root@debian:bin#./opencv_annotation --images=/pos/ --annotations=/pos/annotations.txt`

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(3.4.8) /home/harry/haardev/opencv/modules/core/src/glob.cpp:267: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) could not open directory: /pos in function 'glob_rec'
```

Aborted

Upon getting the above error, I chmod 4777 the director pos/ and its images.  I am still getting this error.  Any ideas?

I am running Debian 10, Buster.

Also, how important is this feature?  Thank you!

Comment: "Also, how important is this feature?" it depends on the use you have to make of it for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opencv requires absolute paths, verify that the `pos` directory is in the root directory or modify the given path accordingly.

> Call the application on your data `opencv_annotation -images /data/image_folder/ -annotations /data/annotations.txt`. Keep in mind
> that the tool loves **absolute paths**, since relative paths can screw up
> the processing.

Also updated version require this syntax (you have used):

`opencv_annotation --images=/data/image_folder/ --annotations=/data/annotations.txt`

Please check the version you are using to identify what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I found that in the docs eventually.